# Getting nonstop nginx code 11: Resource not available

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running a basic wordpress server on Linode.com, with Ubuntu 14.04 and nginx implementations. About two weeks ago, the server began crashing. A server reboot fixes the issue, but after about five hours it only server the "An error occured." page from nginx. The following error shows up in the error log:

```
2015/12/17 19:53:12 [error] 3183#0: *13129 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "45.79.95.93"
```

Is this possibly an issue with the config files, or maybe with the host?

Answer (score 0):

your php5-fpm service has stopped, due to this its socket file is not available in /var/run  location. Please user below command to restart you php5-fpm service

```
service php5-fpm restart
```